# What would be the upper bounds on the accuracy of the algorithm in the below link based on the precision used in the arithmetic operations.

Tags: logarithms

[Algorithm For Calculating Logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61614/682518)

Can you please help?

Comment: Nope, it isn't!

Comment: @user10354138, the question is different but yes it is related to the question you referred.

Comment: I'd say that L4 is executed at most (number of mantissa bits) times, hence the erros accumulated in summing up $y$ are up to that times $\epsilon$, so e.g. with IEEE doubles, the relative error is $<52\cdot 2^{-52}\approx 1.2\cdot 10^{-14}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, thanks. And how are you so good at maths?