# Can you give a method for computing $b^x$ when $0 \le x \lt 1$ using only shifting, addition, and subtraction (similar to the below algorithm)?

Tags: algorithms

Here's the link to the [Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61614/682518)

**Note: The above algorithm is used for computing logarithms.**

I am reading The Art Of Computer Programming Volume 1, and I am stuck. Can you guys help?

Comment: What is $b$? Somehow fixed?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I fixed it! "b" is $b^x$

Comment: $b^x = 2^{x\log_2 b}$.